# MariaDB - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to add a foreign key to a table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_b 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (table_a_id)
REFERENCES table_a(table_a_id)
```

but am getitng te error:

```
[Err] 1005 - Can't create table `my_database`.`#sql-725_92` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

The field in table_a is an auto-incrementing unique key and both fields have the same data type - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the issue, it was because the field table_a.table_a_id had a flag of UNSIGNED, but the field in table_b did not. Once I had updated this, the query worked fine.